# Update every select row result without cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

On my way learning to do different things with tsql. I want to improve my code and would like to get an advice.

Let's say I have this select:

```
SELECT [Id], [Type]
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Id] ORDER BY CurrentDate DESC) AS RowN,
        CS.*
    FROM [CookieStore] CS 
)RN
WHERE RN.RowN = 1
```

Which returns me result table with couple of rows:

```
1) id=5  Type='chocolate'
2) id=6  Type='oatmeal'
3) id=7  Type='gingerbread'
```

To achieve my goal I do cursor over select result to make update:

```
/* some cursor logic */

UPDATE [SweetShop] SET [Type] = @CookieShopType WHERE [Id]=@CookieStoreId

/* some cursor logic */
```

Is there any way to make update for every row from select without cursor? Or in this case there are no other options?

Comment: You can put your select in a CTE, and update the CTE.

Comment: You can use your first query as a subquery that is inner joined with sweetshop, then just update sweetshop.

Comment: @avery_larry you should post that as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform this operstion with a set-based approach (without cursors).

First you define a CTE using your original query, then you can use an `UPDATE FROM` statement to update the target table from a join between the CTE and the target table:

```
;with temp as (
    SELECT [Id], [Type]
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Id] ORDER BY CurrentDate DESC) AS RowN,
            CS.*
        FROM [CookieStore] CS 
    )RN
    WHERE RN.RowN = 1
)
update 
    [SweetShop]
set 
    [Type] = t.[Type]
from
    [SweetShop] as d 
        inner join
    temp as t
        on t.Id = d.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CTE and, also you can avoid writing subquery inside the CTE.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Id] ORDER BY CurrentDate DESC) AS RowN,
        CS.*
    FROM [CookieStore] CS 
)

UPDATE 
    [SweetShop]
SET 
    [Type] = cte.[Type]
FROM
    [SweetShop] as SS 
INNER JOIN
    CTE as C
ON cte.Id = d.Id
WHERE CTE.RowN = 1
```